# Why there is a gap between <UL> and it's container (A drop down menu in wordpress)

Tags: menus, css

This drop down menu works well in HTML but when i move it to wordpress template, there is a gap between  and it's container (.menu-top-container).
when the mouse on the menu you will find the gap.
http://www.jamesxu.com.au/temp/

The funny thing is I copy all the css in the wordpress to a HTML,the gap is gone.Why?

```
.menu-top-container {margin: 0 auto 20px auto; text-align: center; font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif; font-size:1.1em !important; line-height:normal !important;background:#e41f3a;}
.menu-top-container ul ul {display: none;}  
.menu-top-container ul li:hover > ul {display: block;}  
.menu-top-container ul {
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
background:#e41f3a;}
.menu-top-container ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;}
.menu-top-container ul li {float: left;}    
.menu-top-container ul li:hover {
        background: #FFF;}  
.menu-top-container ul li:hover a {color: #333;}                        
.menu-top-container ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 10px 12px;
        color: #FFF; text-decoration: none;}        
.menu-top-container ul ul {
    background: #FFF;  padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;} 
.menu-top-container ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-bottom: 1px  dotted #575f6a; position: relative;}        
.menu-top-container ul ul li a {padding: 5px 30px;color:#FFF;}              
.menu-top-container ul ul li a:hover { background: #e41f3a; color:#FFF;}    
.menu-top-container ul ul ul {position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this `display: inline-table;` is causing the extra space to appear at the bottom. You can fix it by adding `margin: 0 0 -4px;` to the item `.menu-top-container ul li`

I found some help information on these inline objects, [here](http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/).

It seems to be used to center the menu in that navigation, but it's not supported by IE 7 and below. Maybe you can find another way to accomplish the centering that may not require the negative bottom margin?